# Probability amplitude for motion from $x_i$ to $x_f$ in Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, path-integral, time-evolution

In M. Nakahara's book *Geometry, Topology and Physics* on page 19, the probability amplitude for a particle to move from $x_i$ at time $t_i$ to $x_f$ at time $t_f$ is given as

$$
\tag{1}
\langle x_f, t_f | x_i, t_i \rangle
$$

where the Heisenberg picture vectors are defined

$$\tag{2}
\hat{x}(t_i)|x_i, t_i\rangle = x_i|x_i, t_i\rangle
$$

(and similarly for $x_f$) with $\hat{x}(t)$ is the position operator.

I have never seen $(1)$ before. Is that **the** formula for calculating probability amplitudes in the Heisenberg picture? Why are the states dependent on time?

Comment: This tripped me up when I first saw it; $|x, t\rangle$ means the Heisenberg state that has a particle at $x$ at time $t$. That means it's the Schrodinger state that, if it existed at time $t = 0$, would evolve into a particle at $x$ at time $t$.

Comment: To make contact with the definition you know, rewrite these Heisenberg states as Schrodinger states evaluated at $t = 0$. Then you can show that the amplitude is equal to $\langle x_f|U_s(t_f, t_i)|x_i\rangle$ where all the states here are Schrodinger states, which should be familiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I) OP's question (v1) seems to be spurred by a common confusion: The [Heisenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) instantaneous position eigenstate $|x,t_0\rangle_H $ does *not* evolve in time $t$ but *does* depend on a time parameter $t_0$. In detail,

$$\tag{1} | x, t_f \rangle_{H}~=~ e^{i\hat{H}\Delta t/\hbar} | x, t_i \rangle_{H}, \qquad\Delta t~:=~t_f-t_i, $$

where we for simplicity have assumed that the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ has no explicit time dependence.

II) So

$$\tag{2} K(x_f, t_f ; x_i, t_i) 
~=~{}_{H}\langle x_f, t_f | x_i, t_i \rangle_{H}
~=~{}_{H}\langle x_f, t_0 |e^{-i\hat{H}\Delta t/\hbar} | x_i, t_0 \rangle_{H} $$

is the [amplitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude) for a particle going from the initial position $x_i$ at initial time $t_i$ to final position $x_f$ at final time $t_f$.

We usually identify the [Schrödinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture)  and [Heisenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) picture at some fiducial time $t_0$, cf. above comment by Kevin Zhou. The amplitude (2) does not depend on the fiducial time parameter $t_0$.